# Android OpenGL Tiles From Texture Map Appear Misaligned

Tags: android, opengl-es, texture-mapping

I'm trying to do texture mapping in my simple 2D android application, in order to avoid the overhead of OpenGL code for loading each individual tile that I need to render. However, this has made my code much more complex, and I'm running into a very annoying error.

[Here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16ywG.jpg) depicting exactly what is going on. It looks to me like one of two things is happening: either the source coordinates or the destination coordinates used in the texture mapping are slightly off.

The source coordinates I calculated beforehand, finding the appropriate values so I find it hard to believe they are the problem. The destination coordinates are calculated via a "window" over the game world, where the OpenGL coordinate system's origin is shifted to. Then, it iterates over the window, placing the tiles.

I read somewhere that this happens when you use the "pixel edge" coordinates as opposed to "pixel center" coordinates. But I tried shifting the source coordinates by half a pixel (my texture map is 1024x1024, so I added/subtracted 0.5f/1024) and the problem persists.

Has anyone had a similar problem or seen something similar that might lead me down the right path? I'd really hate to have to redesign this graphics system, especially since it's so close.